# Vim: search first match after match of another pattern

Tags: search, vim

How can I find the first occurrence of `bar` after the next occurence of `Foo` using one command/search pattern in Vim?

**Ex:** Suppose I have some text like:

> Bar and bar and bar, I'm such a barbarian.
>
> ...
>
> Foo: That **bar** serves German beer.
>
> Bar bar and bar, so much bar.
>
> Foo: Unrelated.
>
> ...bla
>
> but then next **bar**.

How do I jump between the bolded **bar**s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The first way that came to mind (easy but not repeatable)

You can do something like this:

```
/Foo/;/bar
```

but the "last pattern" will be `bar` so this is not repeatable with `n`, `N`, etc. which means that you will have to do it once and then do `/<Up><CR>`, which may or may not satisfy your needs.

Note that, once you have jumped to the second match, you can do ``` `` ``` to jump back to the first one and ``` `` ``` to jump back to the second one, and so on.

See `:help :;` and ``` :help `` ```.

### The second way that came to mind (more complicated but repeatable)

With a single pattern, and thus repeatable with `n`, `N`, etc., you can do:

```
/Foo\_.\{-}\zsbar
```

where…

- `/Foo` matches the next `Foo`,
- `\_.\{-}` matches any character including EOL, as few as possible,
- `\zs` starts the actual match, discarding what comes before,
- which we want to be `bar`.

See `:help \_.`, `:help \{`, and `:help \zs`.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't figured out a way to combine the following two methods, but they answer your two requests independently.

1. How to find the first occurrence using one command:`:norm /Foo^M/bar^M`
   where `^M` is not typed directly, you must press `ctrl` (or in my case `ctrl+shift`), then press `v`, then `m`. `^M` means enter/return button, so you're basically doing two separate searches in one line. Because they're separate, doing `n` or `N` to move forwards or backwards only moves forward and backwards between `bar`, whether or not they come after a `Foo`. Which leads to:

2. How to move to the next `bar` that comes after `Foo`. You can do this by recording a macro. Press `q` then the letter to store the macro to start recording, then you can do a `/Foo` search, then a `/bar` search. Press `q` again to stop recording. Now you can just do `@a` where `a` is the letter you chose, and that will get you to the next `bar` after the next `Foo`. You can repeat the command to keep searching forward, or you can create another macro for doing the search backwards.

Comment: Thanks! Those were thoughts I had but I have some blurry memory of having seen a direct command for it somewhere...